# What is wrong with my csv data if Liquibase fails with Migration failed for change set ... Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, database-migration, liquibase

The stacktrace is:

```
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20190425094054_added_entity_Kindergarten.xml::20190425094054-1::jhipster:
mental-app_1            |      Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException
mental-app_1            |   at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:637)
mental-app_1            |   at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:53)
mental-app_1            |   at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:83)
mental-app_1            |   at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)
mental-app_1            |   at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179)
mental-app_1            |   at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:353)
mental-app_1            |   at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:305)
mental-app_1            |   at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:119)
mental-app_1            |   at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:104)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
mental-app_1            |   ... 107 common frames omitted
mental-app_1            | Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
mental-app_1            |   at liquibase.change.core.LoadDataChange.retrieveMissingColumnLoadTypes(LoadDataChange.java:628)
mental-app_1            |   at liquibase.change.core.LoadDataChange.generateStatements(LoadDataChange.java:283)
mental-app_1            |   at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1209)
mental-app_1            |   at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:600)
mental-app_1            |   ... 117 common frames omitted
```

the data is loaded by this set up in the changeset:

```
        <loadData
        file="config/liquibase/data/kindergarten.csv"
        separator=";"
        tableName="kindergarten"/>
```

the data itsef is:

```
1,4,xxx yyy 2  ,7 905 555-70-29,"rose place, 11г",john doe
2,7,103,"555-68-72, 555-68-73","address xxx 5, ",emett brown
3,2,34,555-28-49,"z street, 72",""
```

i have updated all empty `,,` to `,"",` to have empty strings rather than nulls there.

So finally the question is how can I enable liquibase debug to define which row in the data contains the problem with the null pointer? For now I have to reveal the prroblematic raw manually

Comment: Your changeset says `separator=";"`, yet all lines have `,` as separator.

Comment: Thank you Roger, please post your comment as the answer!

Comment: but that was not a root cause of the said error

Comment: Have you just exposed user's data (phones, names and addresses) in your question? Whoa!

Comment: @madhead right, I did as my application will do it as all this staff is data from open sources

Comment: your question is being redacted as the data looked real (to protect the people & addresses in the data). Nothing to do with the downvotes BTW

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre who deleted the explanation comment what data it is and that it can't be personal data becode all this staff was duty contacts of the kindergartens, collected from their websites

Comment: moderators deleted it, because it was flagged as sensitive and real data. Anyway there's no need to put real data in here. I think the question is clear enough with the redacted data

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre at the moment of question post the data may contain the reason of the fail, say, lost quotes, that made possible some fields of csv being inerpreted as nulls instead of zero-lenght strings. so in this particular case the data structure itself made some sence. hopefully, the reason was not in formatting itself, but missing headers for them (and the error raised for that was unclear)

Comment: feel free to edit it back to put some relevant data, signalling that the data isn't sensitive. We see people posting passwords & md5 keys all the time that's why.

Comment: and the reason why I have left this question is to help people to find out solution when they will face the same stacktrace under the same conditions. downvotes put the question under the treat of deletion and will make other people to struggle again with the same error with no leading guide this question may be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your changeset configuration the value `separator` is set to `;`, but your CSV file is using `,` as separator. Correct the value in the changeset configuration.

Answer (score 2):

And yes, the similar exception occurs also for the following cases: if the `tableName=""` attribute of the `loadData` points to the wrong table with another structure

Answer (score 0):

So, the said exception was caused by missing the header part of the csv! I have missed `id;district_id;name;phones;address;director` n the first line of the csv